# get browser requests in clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get browser requests in client side i  wrote this code for that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var req = null; try { req = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e)
 { } if (!req) try { req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e)
 { } if (!req) try { req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) { } 
req.open('TRACE', 'http://localhost/Xmlobject.aspx', false);
 req.send(); alert(req.responseText);  </script>
```

but it has following error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:7474/xss1/Xmlobject.aspx :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 7"  data: no]
```

i searched that in google and i found people say that you are not in your domain!!but i'm in localhost.
is there any way for get browser responses?

Answer (score 0):

From [the XHR documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method):

> Throws a "SecurityError" exception if method is a case-insensitive match for CONNECT, TRACE or TRACK.

You can't make HTTP TRACE requests using XHR.